# Renoncer à une opération (me) devenue si difficile

Tags: pronoms, adjectifs, participe-présent

> J'ai dû alors renoncer à une opération **devenue** si difficile...

([source](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Journaux_de_si_A_eges_faits_ou_soutenus/jDBugFFiHKAC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22devenue%20si%20difficile%22&pg=PA500&printsec=frontcover))

Si je réécris cette phrase au présent :

> Je renonce alors à une opération **devenue** si difficile...

Puis, si j'ajoute "me" :

> Je renonce alors à une opération **me devenue** si difficile...

Je trouve très peu d'exemples sur *Google* contenant "me devenu(e)". Donc, est-ce que ma dernière phrase, avec *me devenue si difficile*, est incorrecte ? Si c'est le cas, pourquoi elle est incorrecte ?

Comment: Il me semble que ces questions sont souvent des corrections/révisions.

Comment: Tu dis que tu as trouvé des exemples, peux-tu les citer. Je n'en ai trouvé aucune, je n'ai jamais rencontré une telle construction et je suis curieuse de savoir ce que tu as trouvé.

Comment: @None Peut-être que ce sont des fautes ? _comment supprimer l'adresse XXXX. **me devenue** inutile car remplacée par XXXXX.icloud ?_ [lien](https://communities.apple.com/fr/thread/251905733?page=2)  // OK, seulement un exemple...

Comment: Toutes les ref. citées par LPH sont des erreurs d'OCR, fréquent, c'est pour ça  que les  ref venant de books.google (y compris ngram) ne sont valables que si vérifiées une par une.  Dans le lien que tu mets toi :  « l'adresse XXXX.me devenue inutile »  il s'agit d'une adresse email .me (devenue depuis .icloud ( de la marque à la pomme).  « .me » c'est aussi  un domaine de premier niveau (**me** pour Monténégro, comme fr pour France, etc.), mais je ne pense pas que ce soit ce dont il s'agir d'après le contexte. En tous les cas rien à voir avec un pronom personnel français.

Comment: @None, c'est vrai, c'est une adresse + .me, je ne l'ai pas alors compris.

Answer (score 2):

Ce que tu proposes est impossible en français. Je vois deux possibilités.

1. Quand tu dis « une opération devenue si difficile » tu traites « devenue » comme un adjectif et tu ne peux pas adjoindre un complément  à un adjectif de la sorte. Par contre tu peux considérer qu'une partie de la phrase est sous-entendue et que ce que tu dis est : « une opération qui est devenue si difficile », et en exprimant le groupe verbal en entier tu peux lui adjoindre un complément qui sera placé avant :

> Je renonce alors à une opération qui m'est devenue si difficile...

2. Si tu renonces à mettre ce complément avant le groupe verbal tu peux apporter la précision à l'aide d'une préposition :

> Je renonce alors à une opération qui est devenue  si difficile **pour** moi.

Ou :

> Je renonce alors à une opération devenue si difficile **pour** moi.

Comment: Merci. Et si je mets une virgule, ma phrase restera toujours incorrecte ? _Je renonce alors à une opération**,** me devenue si difficile..._ // _Ou aussi, Je renonce alors à une opération m'**étant** devenue si difficile..._ Je n'aurai pas alors besoin de "qui", si ?

Comment: @Oreste Impossible, même avec une virgule, et le participe présent n'est pas possible non plus. Tu pourrais dire « L'opération m'étant devenue si difficile, j'y renonce »

Comment: Peut-être qu'il serait possible d'ajouter _pour moi_ à la fin et et d'omettre "qui" ? _Je renonce alors à une opération **devenue si difficile pour moi**._ Ou ce serait aussi impossible ?

Comment: @Oreste Oui tout à fait.

Answer (score -2):

Oui, elle est incorrecte, quoique l'on trouve sur Google. Seulement un verbe conjugué ou un infinitif peut être utilisé, ce que « devenue » n'est pas puisque c'est le participe passé de « devenir » dans cette phrase.  Il est nécessaire d'utiliser une forme verbale conjuguée. Comme on ajoute un verbe il faut un pronom relatif pour reprendre « opération » en tant que sujet de ce verbe (puisque ce qui est devenue, c'est l'opération).

- Je renonce alors à une opération qui m'**est devenue** si difficile... (coi)

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Atala_ou_Les_amours_de_deux_sauvages_dan/18QNAAAAQAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22me+devenir%22&pg=PA184&printsec=frontcover)) Cette vie , qui m'avait d'abord enchanté , ne tarda pas à me devenir insupportable.

Comment: «  On trouve énormément de cas (réf.), mais c'est un usage désuet  ». Peux-tu en citer de façons explicites, je suis curieuse sur cette différence français moderne, français « plus ancien » . Je n'ai regardé que les deux premières pages de ta recherche, nombreuses citations extraites des mêmes ouvrages et voici ce que je lis: 1:- « coupera **ME, devenue** » (c'est des maths) ; 2- absent ; 3- « qui est devenue rêveuse » (me  sur la colonne de droite, pas la même phrase)  4- absent ; 5- « réellement devenue indispensable »(me  sur la colonne de droite, pas la même phrase);

Comment: 6-  : « étoit mê**me devenue** si noire ; 7-absent ; 8- la fem**me devenue** veuve ; 9- absent : 10- « je me demande » («  devenue » est sur la colonne de droite, pas la même phrase) ;1 1- absent. Je suppose que toi tu as épluché toutes les pages ?

Comment: @none J'ai seulement regardé les extraits, et en fait ce ne sont que des faux positifs ; comme je n'ai jamais vu cette construction  j'ai conclu qu'elle était désuète. Je vais corriger cette erreur.